# stale mount on linux

Tags: linux, centos, nfs, mount

I am running CentOS 6.9 and randomly one of the nfs mount goes stale and in the log/messages I see the message "server not responding, still trying". Forcing the mount does not work and neither reboot options from cmd. I tried reboot, shutdown -r now, reboot -f, but nothing works. Only option is to hard restart the server.

Any ideas as to what could be the cause and how to sort this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to umount the partition, clear all open file and process which is using that partition, comment that line in fstab, then try **mount -a**, if still not work reboot with commented lines.

Answer (score 0):

you should investigate hard vs soft nfs mount. depending on your requirements soft mount can be better.

most of the time this happens due to network problem, but also it might be the case that nfs server is overloaded and fails to respond in a timely manner.

also, this does not solve the root issue, but you can try to run:

```
reboot -f
```

command as root to instantly reset and reboot your server (might corrupt data).